# Unknown column in 'on clause' codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

when i use this query in codeigniter :

```
        $this->db->where("dopuex_donation_id", $donation_id);
        $this->db->select("donation_purposes_expenses.*, SUM(donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_withdrawn_value) AS count, cases.case_name");
        $this->db->from("donation_purposes_expenses");

        $this->db->join("expenses", "donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_expense_id = expenses.expense_id", "left");
       $this->db->join("cases", "expenses.expense_type = 1 && expenses.expense_case_ref_id = cases.case_ref_id", "left");

        $this->db->group_by("cases.case_name");
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

i got this error

```
 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'

SELECT `donation_purposes_expenses`.*, SUM(donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_withdrawn_value) AS count, `cases`.`case_name` FROM (`donation_purposes_expenses`) LEFT JOIN `expenses` ON `donation_purposes_expenses`.`dopuex_expense_id` = `expenses`.`expense_id` LEFT JOIN `cases` ON `expenses`.`expense_type` = `1` && expenses.expense_case_ref_id = cases.case_ref_id WHERE `dopuex_donation_id` = '34' GROUP BY `cases`.`case_name`
```

it consideres value 1 as field .. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap conditions and put AND between conditions

```
 $this->db->where("dopuex_donation_id", $donation_id);
     $this->db->select("donation_purposes_expenses.*, SUM(donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_withdrawn_value) AS count,
     cases.case_name");
    $this->db->from("donation_purposes_expenses");
    $this->db->join("expenses", "donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_expense_id = expenses.expense_id",
     "left");
    $this->db->join("cases", "expenses.expense_case_ref_id = cases.case_ref_id AND  expenses.expense_type = 1 ", "left");
    $this->db->group_by("cases.case_name");
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `expenses.expense_type = 1` to your where clause.

```php
        $this->db->where("dopuex_donation_id", $donation_id);
        $this->db->where("expenses.expense_type is NULL OR expenses.expense_type = 1", NULL, false); // New where clause !!
        $this->db->select("donation_purposes_expenses.*, SUM(donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_withdrawn_value) AS count, cases.case_name");
        $this->db->from("donation_purposes_expenses");

        $this->db->join("expenses", "donation_purposes_expenses.dopuex_expense_id = expenses.expense_id", "left");
        $this->db->join("cases", "expenses.expense_case_ref_id = cases.case_ref_id", "left");

        $this->db->group_by("cases.case_name");
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Edit: Updated where clause to match also the rows that did not match the `expenses` join. Kind of ugly solution but I do not know codeigniter's syntax very well. Check or_where.

Comment: i can't . i need this condition when only join cases table because i will join another table

Comment: You can check then if expenses.expense_type is null too. Let me update the response.

Comment: Take a look now to the response. I do not know very well codeignite's syntax, there should be some better way to do the same but the idea is: check if expense_type is null (didn't had any matching row in expenses join) or if it did, it is `1`.

Comment: Thanks .. @Dilip Patel give me the correct answer .. thanks for your effort